# Error while connecting to SQL Server using AWS lambda

Tags: python, sql-server, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, pyodbc

I have a flask restful API which works fine on EC2. Its able to connect to AWS SQL Server and can perform fetch/update. But when I upload to AWS lambda I get this error (I am using zappa to upload).

> libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory:    ImportErrorTraceback (most recent call last):  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 609, in lambda_handler    return LambdaHandler.lambda_handler(event, context)  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 240, in lambda_handler    handler = cls()  File "/var/task/handler.py", line 134, in **init**    self.app_module = importlib.import_module(self.settings.APP_MODULE)  File "/var/lang/lib/python3.6/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in import_module    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)  File "", line 994, in _gcd_import  File "", line 971, in _find_and_load  File "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked  File "", line 665, in _load_unlocked  File "", line 678, in exec_module  File "", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed  File "/var/task/app.py", line 8, in 
> import pyodbc
> ImportError: libodbc.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I am using Python 3.6 and have the pyodbc installed in my virtual env and its working fine in EC2

My connection string is this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

details = {
'server' : '*********ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
'database' : '*******',
'username' : '*****',
'password' : '*****'
}
params='DRIVER={{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}};SERVER={server};PORT=1443; DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}'.format(**details)
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(params)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params

#######################
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Is there any dependency like ODBC driver file that i need to place? Please Help

Answer (score 1):

You haven't included the library `libodbc.so` correctly in your Lambda deployment package. It can be fairly complicated to included system binaries like that in your Lambda deployment. [Here's an example](https://gist.github.com/diriver63/b72a954fa0da4851d89e5086aa13c6e8) of what it takes to do that.

Luckily someone has published [a Lambda Layer](https://github.com/alexanderluiscampino/lambda-layers) you can use instead.

Comment: thanks . Also i am a newbie , actually when Iwent to aws interface and added the layer by zip and tried there its working. But how can i add the same layer when i am using zappa. because whenever i do "Zappa update dev". It kind of remove layer also.

Comment: @user3809411 in your local Zappa settings, you would define a `"layers"` setting that includes the ARN of this layer.

Comment: Thanks Mark, I will give this a try

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this using Mark Suggestion. We need to add layers and other settings in zapaa setting file .

```
{
"dev": {
    "app_function": "app.app",
    "aws_region": "ap-south-1",
    "profile_name": "default",
    "project_name": "flask-app",
    "runtime": "python3.7",
    "s3_bucket": "<Name of bucket>",
    "manage_roles": false, 
    "vpc_config": { 
        "SubnetIds": [ <list of all subnet id's>],
        "SecurityGroupIds": [ "<>" ]
    },
    "layers":["<layers arn you want to add>"]
}
```

}